# Counties - US ones but based in UK

Tags: civievent, addresses

I have created an event and want to collect the attendees address including the county.  Although based in the UK, the available options registering on the event page only offer a couple of American ones.  Can this be changed to UK ones?  There are UK options when you create a new contact on CIVI.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to avoid using the drop down field for counties in the UK since - unlike States in the USA, or Departments in France, for example - there is no one true definition for them (is it London, Greater London, Islington, etc.).

Instead, I remove the county drop down and add another supplemental address line if required.

Although there are some forms on the web that use a drop down for counties, I suspect more than half just use a standard text field.

*Flippant side note: the important thing to collect for UK addresses is the awesome UK postcode. As soon as you have that, everything else pales into insignificance :)*

Comment: I agree that County is only a distraction for addresses in the UK. The important thing for delivery is the "Post Town" if you look at the Post Office guide on postal addresses. Counties aren't used, though I recognise that there is some nostalgic attachment to them in addresses in some areas. It really annoys me when I have to enter ....,London, Greater London for my address.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Administer>Localization you can select the available countries and the linked states/counties.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  This seems to be set up correctly.  When I want to create a new contact, the options for county are ones in the UK.  However it's when I create an event and ask people there to fill in their county, it only offers 6 random American ones.

Comment: That can be because the profile you are using with your event only has those options. Did you create the event as sketched in https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/creating-an-event/

Comment: Yes, that's how I created it.  The problem seems to lie in the 'profile' but I can't seem to edit the counties that are in the profiles!  I feel like I'm going round in circles on this things sometimes.

Comment: on the profile do you have a State/Province field - i assume this needs to be hierarchical, ie Country, State/Province, County - and if you don't have them all you would hit issues

Comment: Hi, I don't have an option for a State/Province field.  Perhaps because I have my locality as the UK and we wouldn't have that on an address field?

Comment: Check Administer/Localization/Address Settings? It might well be that State/Province is switched off there?

Answer (score 1):

Add 'State' into the CiviCRM profile that's being used in the event. Be sure to also include the country field.

[image]

Remove county from the profile, this is what is confusing the matter. County in CiviCRM terminolgy means a US State county, State applies to County for the UK.

[image]

The field name 'State' can be renamed to County.